# How to create a 1,5'' square with HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I want to create an interface for a user. That interface have 1,5". Below is the code:

```css
.test{
 height: 52px;
 width: 52px;
 background: black;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="test"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I think those 1,5" are too smaller. What I did to get the 52px was: 
inch -> cm -> pixels

Maybe there is a right way to create that?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Absolute_length_units

Comment: You would have to calculate the correct number of pixels based on the pixel density of the screen. 1.5inch on a retina display would be _much_ larger than 52px.

Comment: @ uʍopǝpısdn One pixel should be equal in every display, no?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#absolute-lengths

Comment: @Miguel No. The size and density of pixels varies dramatically between devices. My 27" imac is 109 pixels per inch. My iphone is 326 pixels per inch. CSS units like `inch` and `cm` are based on the assumption that 1inch = exactly 96px. This is almost certainly not the number of pixels that your users screen will actually display in one physical inch

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn So is there some sort of function or way to display 1.5inch in every display?

Comment: I doubt you could ever do it reliably. Can you explain why the element need to be 1.5inch?

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn it is a requirement

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `in` for the unit?

```css
.test{
 height: 1.5in;
 width: 1.5in;
 background: black;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="test"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That square is approx 1.3inch on my screen at 100% zoom

Comment: wow, I though that all the units need to be in pixels or %. Thanks

Comment: True, but as you said, there is no easy way to do this. Lea Verou's http://dpi.lv code might give a bit of clue on how to do proper calculation but the missing thing there is the diagonal of the screen is a variable that you just have to know or provided to get the accurate measurement.  You can definitely get the width and height from some js properties but that diagonal is a pain...  I supposed asking the user and then recalculate to right size...